# how to run only specific maven module

Tags: maven

how to run only specific maven module from maven eclipse project.

I have few modules in my EAR maven project and when I build whole project it fails at one module WAR,saying this war artifact module not found in repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your multi module project must e having a common parent. First install that parent pom in your local repository. Now go to child module project and maven build the project.
It should work given that all its dependencies are present.